# Pass String from Servlet to jquery using Gson

Tags: jquery, json, servlets, gson

Requirement is very simple

1) Preapre Gson using String Username in servlet doPost --> PASS

```
String userName = "ABC123";
String username = new Gson().toJson(userName, String.class);
httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(username);
```

2) get this username at jquery --> FAIL

```
        $.post('/XYZServlet', function(username) {

        if(username != null) {
            alert('i got username' + username) //here i am getting string as 'success'
            var parsed = JSON.parse(username); //gives error
```

Not able to parse string username, can anyone help?

Comment: Is that because of Gson conversion you are telling ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I am not sure where is the issue, I konw its very simple but I cannot fix

Comment: So you're not running the code you think you're running?

Comment: @BalusC hi god father of java at SO, Yes I am running the code.

Comment: You said you got a string of `"success"` instead of user name as JSON. Most logical cause would that the servlet URL is wrong, or you perhaps haven't properly recompiled/rebuilt/redeployed/restarted the server after modifying the servlet code (if it previously returned `"success"` as kind of test).

Comment: @BalusC I dropped the above idea and implemented solution with another approach. but could you explain why such a small thing cannot work?

Comment: Because you made a mistake which you just didn't see/understand.